# A simple file for saving a class of vectors or a SQL database

Tags: c++, sql, xml, json, database-connection

I have a database that is made of sorted data from the user activities. If I wanted to keep a record of each users that which record belong to which user (like a class of vectors of numbers for each users), what is the best database type that I can use here? The speed is important and the database is very large (9 Gig ~ 700 million record).The number of users is around 2 million, so I don't think that a relational connection in SQL would be a good suggestion. (Coding are in C++).

Comment: Are you limited by a small database server? Any relational database with a decent amount of RAM (16GB should be plenty and cheap) and good indices can handle this load with no problems.

Comment: I have a 8GB system. But beside the memory size, I want to keep the user data somewhere (probably by keeping a record of their record ID number (Primary Key) in a vector), so I can call the records by their record number very fast. If I want to retrieve the user data each time from the database, it would take a lot of time and system wouldn't be fast enough.

Comment: So you want to keep all of this in the same process instead of being in a separate database process? I would recommend an array if you can fit it them. Otherwise, hash would be the way to go. But really, you should use a database. 

But really, you should use a real database just in case your process crashes. For a simple load like this, anything would do. Choose a database that can stay away from the disk (e.g. Redis, MySQL MEMORY table, PostgreSQL with asynchronous commits, ...), and you'll get very good performance.

Comment: I already have a class that I can get the information into the memory as a vector. But since the vectors have different size, I am not sure how I can store them on hard drive efficiently. There are around 2 million users, so if I want to make a user data base with 2 million attached database, that would be impractical I guess.

Comment: Have you tried it and it takes too long, or are you just guessing?  A relational database would be extremely efficient with this given you want to access user information by an id (primary key).  Given that your data is 9Gb+, an in memory solution is not an option for an 8Gb machine.  Besides, you would have to read that whole 9Gb into Memory before starting, a very costly proposition even if you could make it fit.  Instead you would be thrashing your hard disk causing all kinds of slowness.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy I do not have the users' information as a file (prepared). I have to extract them from the database. For example number 1,2,3, and 4 lines of the database are like: 1->(User3, extraction), 2->(User3, deletion), 3-> (User7, copy), and 4-> (User3, Copy). Now I want to reach to the user records very fast. I want to have a vector for each user and in each cell of the vector, I want to keep the record primary key, so I can retrieve them fast. i.e in that example I will have 1-> user3 (1,2,4) , user4 -> (3). If there is a better way for doing that, I would be happy to hear it.

Comment: P.S. I haven't tried it.

Comment: You realize of course that what you are describing is essentially how an index works in a RDBMS.  You create an index over the user id, and when you ask for all instances of User3 the database goes into it's index finds the user3 nodes (which will all be together), finds the physical location of the user3 records in the database, and retrieves them very fast.  The organization of the index makes this about as fast as you can make it.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy Thank you. I have to go through this more and see what is the best way of handling this

Comment: @jmarkmurphy Is there any command (I am using SQLite) that would do it or should I write the indexing code on my own? (CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name
ON table_name ( column1, column2,...columnN);)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to provide an answer now based on our conversation in the comments as I have too much to write in a comment.

First of all, I would use a full RDBMS for this rather than SQLite. The Lite part of the name should serve as an indicator that it isn't trying to be a full strength database. I am just saying this because if SQLite does not perform well enough on your large database, I don't want you to blame it on RDBMS technology, but on the weak database that you are using.  Choose PostgreSQL or MySQL as they have better optimizers (you don't have to code it).

Second your database should provide the features to join the tables together.  It would look something like:

```
Select *
From users
  Join activity on users.id = activity.user_id
Where users.id = ###
```

That combined with the appropriate indexes should give you what you need.

As far as indexes, your primary keys should produce the appropriate indexes for this join.  You can also create a foreign key definition so that the database knows the relationship between the tables, and can enforce it.  Some databases do not support foreign key constraints, but that is not critical.

Comment: @POD: Just FYI: If you use MySQL (not via ODBC), then your program has to be GPL, or you need to buy a MySQL commercial license from Oracle Corp., Inc. If you use MySQL via ODBC and deploy the ODBC driver together with your application, then you even need a license when you use ODBC. Therefore, I recommend you go with PostGre, not MySQL.

Comment: GPL does not mean you have to distribute your application, it just means that anyone you share your code with is free to do so as well if they wish.

Comment: In fact the GPL FAQ says _However, in many cases you can distribute the GPL-covered software alongside your proprietary system. To do this validly, you must make sure that the free and non-free programs communicate at arms length, that they are not combined in a way that would make them effectively a single program._ That tells me that as long as MySQL is not embedded in your application, you can use it without making your application GPL.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy: Absolutely not, the MySQL "drivers" (data access libraries) are GPL as well, and if your program uses them (dynamically links against them), your program becomes GPL. They are not LGPL, and that's the point (think about it - you wouldn't need to buy a commercial license otherwise...).

Comment: So you are disputing the FAQ on the GPL site?  with Open source software, typically the only reason to purchase a commercial license is to get support. Oracle's site says _OEMs, ISVs and VARs that want the benefits of embedding commercial binaries of MySQL software in their commercial applications but do not want to be subject to the GPL and do not want to release the source code for their proprietary applications should purchase a commercial license from Oracle._ So basically what I said above. Not "if you want to use the drivers".

Answer (score 1):

A relational SQL database can handle this just well.
Use PostGreSQL 
You can use ODBC from C, that way you can change the database should the need arise.

If your data is not really relational, you can also use redis.
http://code.google.com/p/credis/

Comment: I am using SQLite for my coding. I need to keep it light. But how can i make that relational connection? Is there a command that would do create a table and make the connection between two tables automatically in SQL or should I extract all the users ID first and put it in a table and then make the connection?

Answer (score 1):

Since its a sorted set of data, you can event go for a NoSQL or [Bigtable](http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable.html) database. [HBase](http://hbase.apache.org/), [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/), etc are provided OpenSouce resources for you.

Comment: I already did the coding with SQL. The data is not completely sorted by time. In small portions, each portion of data is sorted based on the users (like putting data every hours into the database that is not sorted on time). My biggest problem here is how can I connect the two tables (the users and the activity of the users) that is timely efficient and I don't go for a self coding of a databas.